# Spring boot application.properties doesn't work with multiple profiles

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

I have 2 issues trying to connect to dynamodb in aws. It's working locally:

```
@Configuration
class DynamoDbConfig {
    @Value("${amazon.access.key}")
    private String awsAccessKey;

    @Value("${amazon.access.secret.key}")
    private String awsSecretKey;

    @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.endpoint}")
    private String awsDynamoDBEndPoint;

    @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.region}")
    private String awsDynamoDBRegion;

    @Bean
    public AWSCredentials amazonAWSCredentials() {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
    }

    public AWSCredentialsProvider amazonAWSCredentialsProvider() {
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(amazonAWSCredentials());
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamoDB dynamoDB() {
        AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB =  AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(awsDynamoDBEndPoint, awsDynamoDBRegion))
                .withCredentials(amazonAWSCredentialsProvider())
                .build();

        return new DynamoDB(amazonDynamoDB);
    }

}
```

application-local.properties

```
amazon.access.key=key1
amazon.access.secret.key=key2
amazon.dynamodb.endpoint=http://localhost:8000
amazon.dynamodb.region=us-east-1
```

application-prod.properties

```
amazon.access.key=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
amazon.access.secret.key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
amazon.dynamodb.endpoint=dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
amazon.dynamodb.region=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
```

I already got credentials and my .aws/credentials looks good:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = MyKeyId
aws_secret_access_key = MySecretKey
aws_session_token = blablabla
disney_session_expiration = This is also ok
```

1 Issue) It looks like always take the application-local.properties profile, if I show the awsAccessKey and awsSecretKey in the class DynamoDbConfig, I get key1 and key2. I tried with these 2 commands:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
mvn spring-boot:run -Pprod
```

2 Issue) I renamed application-prod.properties as application.properties to make spring takes that config file and I get this error message:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY' in value "${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
```

Comment: if you are using spring boot 2+ then try `mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=prod`

Comment: You can also set an active profile in `application.properties` file, using `spring.profiles.active=prod`

Comment: I'm using 2.3.1 but that command you provided me didn't work

Comment: I tried with spring.profiles.active=local in the application.properties and worked. But I'd like to active the profile by command line as then I have to deploy it and it's not good has to change application.properties everytime. Also still doesnt work the issue 2

Comment: It also depends on maven build plugin, try `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=prod` & `mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=prod"`

Comment: The first command worked. Thanks.... however I'm stil having the issue 2: Could not resolve placeholder 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID' in value "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"

Comment: Where `${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}`  is defined? In the `local` profile, you have hard coded, but in the `prod` profile you are referring to property - `${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}` which is not defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218155/discussion-between-thirumal-and-julio).

Comment: yes weren't defined. I got confused because it's supposed you don't have to define those properties once the service is running in aws. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `profile` is not an issue, the values are not set/defined for the following keys

```
${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
```